# Why do French people use “en fait” so often?

Tags: sens, langage-informel

Is there any meaning to it besides “actually”? Because I’ve seen it used so so often in informal French and it seems almost like a filler word.

Answer (score 2):

It can be exactly that, filler, or rather as I see it, a bad habit contracted somehow from listening to people having the same bad habit or maybe from people that use the word properly;  it shouldn't be inferred from this spurious usage that the word is empty, it's not; it corresponds among other possibilities to "actually" or "as a matter of fact" in English when used correctly.

— You should buy some of those as soon as you can, they're great !
*Tu devrais en acheter aussitôt que possible, il sont excellents!*
— I know ! As a matter of fact, I already did.
 *Je sais! En fait, j'en ai déjà achetés.*